# Get List of Records that do not exist in another list - Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to return a list of users to disable if they do not exist in another list.

Here is what I am currently trying but it is not working:

```
var disableUserList = dbUserList.Where(ds => dsUserList.Any(db => db.GlobalIdentity != ds.GlobalIdentity)).ToList();
```

Comment: So you want all the dbUsers that are not in the dsUser list and the users share a property called GlobalIdentity?

Comment: Have you tried the [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq-extension?

Comment: *What* is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to negate your logic.  Your current logic will always return true, because the dsUserList most likely has an entry where the GlobalIdentity does not match your dbUserList entry.  So, if there are any in the dsUserList where there's a match, exclude them:

```
var disableUserList = dbUserList.Where(ds => !dsUserList.Any(db => db.GlobalIdentity == ds.GlobalIdentity)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

As DmitryG pointed out, Except works great for this situation. Here's a quick example where out of users 'A', 'B', 'C', only 'A' is enabled so 'B' and 'C' are written to the console:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var activeList = new List<string> { "A" };
        var userList = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};

        var removalList = userList.Except(activeList);

        foreach (var item in removalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();    
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with `Except(some local list)` in LINQ to a SQL back end. The local list should contain primitive values and if it does, it can't be too long. And LINQ to SQL simply doesn't support it

Answer (score 2):

You can do a left join in Linq with `DefaultIfEmpty` and filter on non joined entries (null records).

```
var query = from u in dbUserList
            join g in dsUserList on u.GlobalIdentity equals g.GlobalIdentity
            into joinedUsers
            from ju in joinedUsers.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ju == null
            select u;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Any` with `All`.

```
var disableUserList = dbUserList.Where(ds => dsUserList.All(db => db.GlobalIdentity != ds.GlobalIdentity)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If table is one to one relationship then this is better query

```
var disableUserList = (from ds in dbUserLists
                       join db in dsUserLists on ds.GlobalIdentity  equals db.GlobalIdentity into tmp from db in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where
                           db.GlobalIdentity == null
                       select ds).ToList()
```

If not

```
var disableUserList = (from ds in dbUserLists                      
                   where
                        !db.dbUserLists.Any(db => db.GlobalIdentity == ds.GlobalIdentity)
                   select ds).ToList()
```

or

```
var disableUserList = dbUserList.Where(ds => !dsUserList.Any(db => db.GlobalIdentity == ds.GlobalIdentity)).ToList();
```